# wait for value to be assigned to to variable

Tags: python, python-asyncio, variable-assignment

I Have this code where I'm waiting for some receipt of a successful transaction so I can extract some data.
The problem is when I do it in real time, the coded crashes because the `transaction_tx` is not found directly after I buy some crypto, it takes a few seconds.
That's why I make the program sleep for 10 seconds.

I would like to find a way to wait for the receipt variable to actually get something stored:

```py
receipt = web3provider.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transaction_tx)
```

Maybe I don't understand `async/await` good enough but when waiting for a variable to get a value assigned it is not a solution..., so the only thing I can think of is doing a try and catch the error and then a `time.sleep(1)` and then repeat to check if something is in the variable.
Would that be a correct solution or is there a more obvious way?

```py
import json
from ast import literal_eval
import time
from web3 import Web3
bsc = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'
web3provider = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))

def getTradedAmount(tokenAddress, transaction_tx):
    time.sleep(10)
    receipt = web3provider.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transaction_tx)
    tx_json = Web3.toJSON(receipt)
    json_obj = json.loads(tx_json)
    log = json_obj['logs']
    length = len(log)
    for t in range(length):
        dec = literal_eval(log[t]['data'])
        if log[t]['address'] == tokenAddress:
            amountData = log[t]['data']

    print(amountData)


tx = "0x76094c8541e318fd2fa4479d48184cd66323d63fd889a3f30b973242f55eabbe"
token ="0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56"

#transaction_tx = buy(tokenAddress, 0.001)

getTradedAmount(token, tx)
```

the error i get is this:

```
web3.exceptions.TransactionNotFound: Transaction with hash: '0xfb0460c094b55f718fdf9b7fc49087d6586bfbc4886fd64e01f5eee4d11d48d5' not found.
```

Comment: What is returned when the transaction ticket is not available? `None`?

Comment: @user56700 I printed a dump of the error, the transaction tx is existing is just cant find it yet, it needs a few seconds. thats why i put in time.sleep then it works